# Understanding the ternary operator

Tags: php, ternary

I have the following example:

```
$a=false;
$b=true;
$c=false;
if($a ? $b : $c){
   echo 'false';
} else {
   echo 'true';
}
```

I can't seem to understand this statement,and i need someone to explain me how it works...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is vague, broad and probably just involves reading the manual.

Comment: The only thing you need to do to understand this is "unpack" the ternary expression `$a ? $b : $c` then replace the result inside the `if` [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a=false;
$b=true;
$c=false;
if($a ? $b : $c){
   echo 'false';
} else {
   echo 'true';
}
```

expands to:

```
$a=false;
$b=true;
$c=false;
if ($a) {
  $temp = $b; // TRUE
} else {
  $temp = $c; //FALSE
}
if($temp){
   echo 'false';
} else {
   echo 'true';
}
```

because `$a` is false, `$temp` is assigned `$c` value (which is false), second if checks if $temp is true (which is not), so else statement is executed `echo 'true'`

Answer (score 1):

It's an equivalent of this:

```
<?php

$a = false;
$b = true;
$c = false;

if(($a && $b) || (!$a && $c)) {
  echo 'false';
} else {
  echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: Hmm, now I wonder if somebody considers my answer wrong or if somebody is getting upset that I'm answering a question he/she thinks should not be here at all.